# update using oracledataadapter

Tags: updates

I am using the following lines of code to update records based on rowid:
here dsmain the dataset that i am using....

For j = 2 To AuditGrid.Rows - 1

```
        If AuditGrid.ActiveCell.Row = j And AuditGrid.ActiveCell.Col = ColMark Then
            Uvalue = Trim(AuditGrid.Cell(j, ColMark).Text)
            da.UpdateCommand = New OracleCommand("update audit01 set user" & Trim(User) & "='" & Trim(Uvalue) & "' where audit01.rowid='" & Trim(AuditGrid.Cell(j, ColWRowid).Text) & "'")
        End If
    Next

    da.Fill(DsMain, "AUDIT01")
    da.Update(DsMain, "AUDIT01")
    DsMain.AcceptChanges()
```

the problem is that the database is not being updated. what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used the following lines of code and it now works perfectly fine...

If AuditGrid.ActiveCell.Row > 0 Then

```
        Uvalue = Trim(AuditGrid.Cell(AuditGrid.ActiveCell.Row, ColMark).Text)
        strQry = "update audit01 set user" & Trim(User) & "='" & Trim(Uvalue) & "' where rowidtochar( audit01.rowid)='" & AuditGrid.Cell(AuditGrid.ActiveCell.Row, ColWRowid).Text & "'"
        da = New OracleDataAdapter(strQry, con)
        da.Fill(DsMain)
        DsMain.AcceptChanges()
        MsgBox("Record Updated!!")
        AuditGrid.Range(AuditGrid.ActiveCell.Row, ColMark, AuditGrid.ActiveCell.Row, ColMark).DeleteByRow()
    End If
```